# Problems in running oozie with hadoop

Tags: oozie, hadoop2

I'm trying to run oozie 4.2.0 on hadoop 2.7.0 working in a psudo-distributed mode on my local machine. 
I built a distro of oozie binding it to the correct hadoop version I'm using, then, according to the documentation I did the following steps

```
<ul>
<li>Created a folder called <b>libext</b> where I put a .zip of <i>ext-2.2</i> library</li>
<li>Lauched the commands 

    oozie-setup.sh prepare-war 
    ooziedb.sh create -sqlfile oozie.sql -run
    oozied.sh start
```

Everything went fine, in fact I can navigate `<code>localhost:11000/oozie/</code>` and also if, i execute `<code>oozie admin -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -status</code>` the server replies with `<b>NORMAL</B>`.

However I'm not able to launch any jobs, neither the examples. After moving the example folder in the correct position on HDSF if I execute `<br> <code>oozie job -oozie localhost:11000/oozie -config /path/to/examples/apps/map-reduce/job.properties -run</code>`

The server replies with

> Error: HTTP error code: 500 : Internal Server Error.

Same situation if I try to submit a workflow programmatically using the Java API.

Looking at the `<code>oozie.log</code>` file I get the following error/warning:

> ERROR V2AdminServlet:517 - SERVER[Matteos-MBP.vimond.local] USER[-] 
>   GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[-] ACTION[-] URL[GET http://localhost:11000/oozie/v2/admin/instrumentation?_dc=1437056225186] error, null
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService.getLatestLibPath(ShareLibService.java:687)
>       at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService$7.getValue(ShareLibService.java:742)
>       at org.apache.oozie.service.ShareLibService$7.getValue(ShareLibService.java:737)
>       at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.instrElementsToJson(BaseAdminServlet.java:312)
>       at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.instrToJson(BaseAdminServlet.java:339)
>       at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.sendInstrumentationResponse(BaseAdminServlet.java:396)
>       at org.apache.oozie.servlet.V2AdminServlet.sendInstrumentationResponse(V2AdminServlet.java:124)
>       at org.apache.oozie.servlet.BaseAdminServlet.doGet(BaseAdminServlet.java:127)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)

everytime I refresh the webapp interface and

```
AuthenticationToken ignored:   
org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.util.SignerException: Invalid  
signature
```

Every-time I submit a workflow either via command line or java API

**My working environment:** 
Mac Os Yosemite 
java version "1.8.0_45" 
Hadoop 2.7.0 
oozie 4.2.0 
Apache Maven 3.3.3

Can anyone help me to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem at first deploying the ShareLib into the HDFS and then manually upgrading common-io library from 2.1 to 2.4 version. I don't have anymore exceptions and I can submit jobs to oozie-server

Source: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/oozie-user/201507.mbox/browser